# Test for presence or absence of a record in CloudKit with Swift 2

Tags: swift, cloudkit, tvos

I am writing a tvOS app. I want to test to see if there's a record in CloudKit database.

I am trying to do this by seeing if there is a record with an specific `eventID`.

Ideally, I want to call a function that returns true or false:

```
if isEventInWatchListFile(eventID) {
 // ... do things
}
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
 var results = [AnyObject]()
 var onList:Bool?

 . . .

    func isEventInWatchListFile(eventID: String) -> Bool {

        let container = CKContainer(identifier: "the container")
        let privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventID == %@",eventID)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "UserWatchlist", predicate: predicate)

        privateDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results , error in
            guard let results = results else {
                // error handler to come
                return
            }

            if results[0]["eventID"] != nil {

              self.onList = true

            } else {

              self.onList = false
            }
        }

        return self.onList!
    }
```

This crashes with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I think this is because `onList` is locked up in a closure. I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to pass out `onList` to the `return` statement, and, if so, how? I've read up on closures in Swift, but not sure how to apply what I've read.

2) Is there a better way to do the test I want to do? My approach seems clunky to me.

I am very new to iOS and Swift. Any help greatfully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, your statement

```
return self.onList!
```

will always fail, because you are setting the value asynchronously and the default (nil) value is passed to the return before the asynchronous operation ends.

Instead of `func isEventInWatchListFile(eventID: String) -> Bool` you could create something like `func doSomethingEventInWatchListFile(eventID: String, funcToRunIfEventIsInTheWatchList: () -> Void)`. Then you would have:

```
        if results[0]["eventID"] != nil {

          funcToRunIfEventIsInTheWatchList()

        } else ...
```

Comment: MirekE, thanks a lot. You are of course correct and your strategy makes sense. In the context of the larger data model, I'll have to restructure some things, but your idea gives me a way forward.